# TypeScript code weaving

Tags: typescript, compile-time-weaving

Is there a way to do code weaving in TypeScript?

What I'm trying to do is inject a piece of code as the very first line of every function in my TypeScript app and I don't wont to do this manually (this manual approach is tedious and error prone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not true *compile*-time weaving, for class methods only you can use [method decorators](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#method-decorators) to wrap those methods with additional functionality at *runtime*. Consider this example method decorator, which makes invocation also log the received arguments into the console:

```
// the method decorator function
function log(target: Object, key: string, descriptor: any) {
    // replace original property descriptor of method with the following one:
    return {
        // the new method:
        value: function (...args: any[]) {
            // log arguments
            console.log(args);

            // invoke the original method as part of the new method,
            // and return its returned value (if any)
            return descriptor.value.apply(this, args);
        }
    };
}
```

Applying this decorator to a method is as trivial as:

```
class Calculator {
    @log
    add(a: number, b: number) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

---

Quick explanation: a method decorator in Typescript has the following signature:

```
<T>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor<T>) => PropertyDescriptor<T> | void;
```

In other terms, the method decorator takes in 3 arguments:

1. The prototype object on which the original method is defined
2. The property key of the method
3. The property descriptor of the method

A method decorator returns a single property descriptor, which is a replacement for that of the original method on the type.

Comment: I was reading the [exact same thing](http://goo.gl/rE21Hu) :) I think that decorators are appropriate for the problem but I still need to manually decorate every single method, is there a way to avoid this? Can I "implicitly" decorate every methods?

Comment: @Gigitsu You could use a [class decorator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#class-decorators) to decorate all methods of a type (by iterating over own properties of the prototype and see if they are functions), but I know no way for automatically adding method decorators to *every single method* in your entire codebase.